# How to determine database type for a given JDBC connection?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I need to handle resultsets returning stored procedures/functions for three databases (Oracle, sybase, MS-Server). The procedures/functions are generally the same but the call is a little different in Oracle.

```
statement.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
...
statement.execute(); 
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)statement.getObject(1);
```

JDBC doesn't provide a generic way to handle this, so I'll need to distinguish the different types of DBs in my code.  I'm given the connection but don't know the best way to determine if the DB is oracle.  I can use the driver name but would rather find a cleaner way.

Answer (score 57):

I suspect you would want to use the DatabaseMetaData class.  Most likely [DatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseProductName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getDatabaseProductName--) would be sufficient, though you may also want to use the getDatabaseProductVersion method if you have code that depends on the particular version of the particular database you're working with.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server gives "Microsoft SQL Server" for the product name.

Comment: PostgreSQL gives "PostgreSQL"

Comment: MySQL gives "MySQL", and HSQLDB gives "HSQL Database Engine".

Comment: Derby gives "Apache Derby"

Comment: Is there an enum we could use to compare ?

Comment: Most other values are listed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320200/inline-blob-binary-data-types-in-sql-jdbc/58736912#58736912

Comment: H2 gives "H2" .

Answer (score 3):

You can use org.apache.ddlutils, class [Platformutils](http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/api/org/apache/ddlutils/PlatformUtils.html):

```
databaseName = new PlatformUtils().determineDatabaseType(dataSource)
```