# Inline BLOB / BINARY data types in SQL / JDBC

Tags: sql, jdbc, binary, blob, inline

Let's say I want to avoid using bind variables in JDBC and run SQL using "ad-hoc" statements, e.g:

```
connection.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT ...");
```

Is there any convention / JDBC escape syntax to inline BLOB data types? I know that [H2 has this syntax](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#bytes):

```
INSERT INTO lob_table VALUES (X'01FF');
```

But that's not a standard. Any general solutions? Note, I'm interested in a general approach. I know that this can turn out to be terribly inefficient.

Comment: If it's a Text field and not Image most DBMS's will accept a string. If you want to get non-text info in there you could shift it to hex, expensive though that.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: I have no knowledge of the data's semantics, so I have to assume it's actually binary data. So you're saying that most DB's do accept hex strings?

Comment: In Text blob, yes. Image, I have no idea, never tried to do it. Hmmm perhaps Convert(VarBinary(),"SomeString" might be a goer as well, as a sudden thought

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: That seems to be SQL Server-specific. Nice to know how it works, but generally for this question it's out of scope. I'm just looking for `BLOB` / `BINARY` data types

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There probably isn't a JDBC escape syntax, so I searched around a bit and found and successfully tested the following:

- SQL Server, Sybase ASE, Sybase SQL Anywhere

  ```
  INSERT INTO lob_table VALUES (0x01FF);
  ```
- DB2

  ```
  -- Use a blob constructor. This is not needed for VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA types
  INSERT INTO lob_table VALUES (blob(X'01FF'));
  ```
- Derby, H2, HSQLDB, Ingres, MySQL, SQLite

  ```
  INSERT INTO lob_table VALUES (X'01FF');
  ```
- Oracle

  ```
  -- As mentioned by a_horse_with_no_name, keep in mind the relatively low
  -- limitation of Oracle's VARCHAR types to hold only 4000 bytes!
  INSERT INTO lob_table VALUES (hextoraw('01FF'));
  ```
- Postgres

  ```
  -- There is also hex encoding as of Postgres 9.0
  -- The explicit cast is important, though
  INSERT INTO lob_table VALUES (E'\\001\\377'::bytea);
  ```

  See [A.H.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320200/inline-blob-binary-data-types-in-sql-jdbc#9324883) for more details about Postgres' hex encoding
- SQL Standard

  ```
  -- SQL actually defines binary literals as such 
  -- (as implemented by DB2, Derby, H2, HSQLDB, Ingres, MySQL, SQLite):
  <binary string literal> ::=
    X <quote> [ <space>... ] 
    [ { <hexit> [ <space>... ] <hexit> [ <space>... ] }... ] <quote>

  <hexit> ::=
    <digit> | A | B | C | D | E | F | a | b | c | d | e | f
  ```

Comment: Very good compilation. Note that Oracle's has a limit of 4000 characters for character literals which also applies for the hextoraw() function. That limits the max. size of the blob that you can create like that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Nice hint. That probably applies to some of the other databases too, which tend to have similar (yet larger) limits for `varchar`

Comment: Did you actually used/suceeded in using the derby version? It does not work for me. I tried X'AABB' and (CAST(X'AABB' AS BLOB))

Comment: @eckes: Yes this works as documented above and is implemented this way in [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org). In what context did you try this (i.e. what's the full statement)?

Comment: @LukasEder Yes you are right, `INSERT INTO tBlob(cID, cBlob) VALUE ("1",CAST(X'010203' AS BLOB))` actually works with Derby. My problems seems to be [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org) related. BTW: without the cast it does not work, it returns: `ERROR 42821: Columns of type 'BLOB' cannot hold values of type 'CHAR () FOR BIT DATA'.` which is expected according to the Derby spec.

Comment: @eckes: *"BTW: without the cast it does not work"*: Yes that might be true. Derby is very picky with data types...

Comment: Note of the obvious: At least in MySQL, BLOBs are a specific type of string. So where useful, "normal" string literals also work as BLOB literals: `INSERT INTO lob_table VALUES ('abc')`

Comment: Beware that `VALUES (0x01FF)` is applicable only for tiny values fitting in about 8 bytes of numeric data type. Any longer values would require string literals and explicit casts like in [insert varbinary value from hex literal in Microsoft SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507385/insert-varbinary-value-from-hex-literal-in-microsoft-sql-server).

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add some PostgreSQL specific stuff to [Lukas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9320943/947357):

The shortest and most easiest solution would be (since PostgreSQL 9.0 at least):

```
insert into lob_table (data) values( E'\\x0102030405FF' )
```

without any cast (if the column is already a `bytea` one) and only **one** `\\x` mark right at the beginning. This is the "hex format" documented in the section [Binary Data Types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/datatype-binary.html).

Regarding the `X'01FF'` syntax: According to the [string constant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS) documentation PostgreSQL does support it - for bit strings. And it seems, that there is no standard conversion from bit to bytea.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the addition. I don't know what I did wrong, but in my Postgres instance (9.0), the hex variant didn't seem to work when running `select E'\\x01FF'`. But maybe I was missing some detail

Comment: Does is work now? I tested on 9.1. My guess: You used `E'\\x01\\xFF'` which indeed does not work :-)

Comment: It actually works. It's just my nonsensical hex code `01FF` which has no useful correspondance in utf-8, which is why it was still escaped in the output. DUH! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
public String binaryLiteral(Connection con, byte[] bytes) {
    String databaseName = con.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName();
    String binary = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes);
    switch (databaseName) {
        case "Microsoft SQL Server":
        case "Sybase Anywhere": case "ASE": case "Adaptive Server Enterprise": // Sybase
            return "CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '0x" + binary + "', 1)";
        case "Oracle":
            if (binary.length() <= 4000) {
                return "HEXTORAW('" + binary + "')";
            } else {
                // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116634/oracle-10-using-hextoraw-to-fill-in-blob-data/62162036#62162036
                return "CONCAT_RAWS(RAWS(" +
                        Streams.stream(Splitter.fixedLength(4000).split(binary))
                                .map(chunk -> "HEXTORAW('" + chunk + "')")
                                .collect(Collectors.joining(",")) +
                        "))";
            }
        case "PostgreSQL":
            return "E'\\\\x" + binary + "'";
        case "H2":
        // the following list is mostly untested
        case "HSQL Database Engine":
        case "Apache Derby":
        case "Ingres":
        case "MySQL":
        case "MariaDB":
        case "SQLite":
        case "Informix Dynamic Server":
        case "DB2":
        case "Firebird":
        default: // SQL Standard
            return "X'" + binary + "'";
    }
```

The source for `CONCAT_RAWS` and `RAWS` is given in [Oracle 10: Using HEXTORAW to fill in blob data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116634/oracle-10-using-hextoraw-to-fill-in-blob-data/62162036#62162036).