# insert varbinary value from hex literal in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, mssql-jdbc

I have a SpringBoot app, where I use jdbcTemplate to insert a row to a mssql

```
int numOfRowsAffected = remoteJdbcTemplate.update("insert into dbo.[ELCOR Resource Time Registr_]  "
                + "( [Entry No_], [Record ID], [Posting Date], [Resource No_], [Job No_], [Work Type], [Quantity], [Unit of Measure], [Description], [Company Name], [Created Date-Time], [Status] ) "
                + " VALUES (?,CONVERT(varbinary,?),?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);",

                ELCORResourceTimeRegistr.getEntryNo(), 
                ELCORResourceTimeRegistr.getEntryNo()), 
                ELCORResourceTimeRegistr.getPostingDate(),
                ELCORResourceTimeRegistr.getResourceNo(), 
                jobNo,
                ELCORResourceTimeRegistr.getWorkType(), 
                ELCORResourceTimeRegistr.getQuantity(),
                ELCORResourceTimeRegistr.getUnitOfMeasure(), 
                ELCORResourceTimeRegistr.getDescription(),
                ELCORResourceTimeRegistr.getCompanyName(), 
                ELCORResourceTimeRegistr.getCreatedDate(), 
                0);
```

the value of `ELCORResourceTimeRegistr.getEntryNo()` is a String with the value `0x00173672`

but what is inserted in the DB is `<30007800 30003000 31003700 33003600 37003200>`

```
ELCORResourceTimeRegistr.getEntryNo().getClass().getCanonicalName() => java.lang.String
```

Comment: What does `ELCORResourceTimeRegistr.getEntryNo().getClass().getCanonicalName()` return?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [documentation for the CONVERT function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#binary-styles) says that the default "style" for binary types is `0`:

> Translates ASCII characters to binary bytes, or binary bytes to ASCII characters. Each character or byte is converted 1:1.

So,

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY, '0x00173672') AS foo;
```

returns

```
foo
--------------------------------------------------------------
0x30783030313733363732
```

which are the ASCII byte values of the hex literal, not the hex bytes themselves. In order for CONVERT to *interpret* the hex literal, you need to use style `1`, i.e.

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY, '0x00173672', 1) AS foo;
```

which returns

```
foo
--------------------------------------------------------------
0x00173672
```

Comment: FYI if you don't want larger data to be truncated use `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), ...)`